# Mixed Jetpack Compose / Activity app navigation: from compose to activity and back

Tags: android-activity, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am a newbie in Android development so I might be missing something simple here.

I have a compose setup using `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3` where I have  the routing setup:

```
sealed class Routes(val route: String) {
    object Login : Routes("Login")
    object TermsOfService : Routes("TermsOfService")
    object Home : Routes("Home")
}

@Composable
fun Routing(startDestination: String) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
        composable(Routes.Login.route) {
            LoginPage(navController = navController, LoginViewModel(AppEnvironment.sdk))
        }

        composable(Routes.TermsOfService.route) {
            TermsOfService(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(Routes.Home.route) {
            Home(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

I would setup my `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            App_SenderTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val isLoggedIn = AppEnvironment.encryptedSettingsRepo.isUserLoggedIn.get().toBoolean()
                    println("Routing based on is_user_logged_in $isLoggedIn")

                    if (isLoggedIn) {
                        Routing(startDestination = Routes.Home.route)
                    } else {
                        Routing(startDestination = Routes.Login.route)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Home` itself is an Activity setup like:

```
@Composable
fun Home(navController: NavHostController) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        ScaffoldWithTopBarHome(navController)
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun ScaffoldWithTopBarHome(navController: NavHostController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CustomTopAppBar(navController, "Sender", true)
        }, content = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                val context = LocalContext.current
                context.startActivity(Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java))
            }
        })
}

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun logout() {
       // HOW TO GO BACK TO COMPOSE IF I DON'T HAVE A COMPOSE NAVIGATION REFERENCE
    }
}
```

I can easily navigate to the `HomeActivity` from any composable setup since I have the `NavHostController`, e.g. `navController.navigate(Routes.Home.route)`, but how can I navigate back from the "activityworld` back to compose land.

Thanks.